# Gulp+Typescript+Browsersync Slow to compile

Tags: typescript, gulp, browser-sync, gulp-typescript, gulp-watch

I have defined a gulp task to watch `.ts` files and compile the typescript on file changes. BrowserSync then detects js file changes and reloads the page. When I change some .ts file and save, the whole compilation + file change detection process takes more than 30s up to 1min sometimes, which is for me a lot. I don't want to wait 1min for the project (which really isn't so big) to compile, it gets quickly very annoying.

Here are the relevant parts in my `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('typescript', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/**/*.ts')
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(plugins.typescript(tscConfig.compilerOptions))
        .pipe(plugins.tokenReplace({tokens:config[process.env.NODE_ENV || envDev]}))
        .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'));
});
gulp.task('watch:ts', function () {
    gulp.watch('app/**/*.ts', ['typescript']);
});
gulp.task('build', ['less', 'typescript']);
gulp.task('serve', ['build', 'watch:less', 'watch:ts'], function(cb) {
    browserSync.init({
        injectChanges: false, // workaround for Angular 2 styleUrls loading
        files: ['./**/*.{html,htm,css,js}'],
        server: {
            baseDir: './',
        },
        open: false
    });
});
gulp.task('build', ['less', 'typescript']);
```

If I run the `gulp typescript` task alone I get it compiled in ~10s, which is good:

```
amaurymartiny$ gulp typescript
[23:32:57] Using gulpfile ~/Workspace/monbanquet/monbanquet-front-admin/gulpfile.js
[23:32:57] Starting 'typescript'...
(I truncated some typescript errors here)
[23:33:07] TypeScript: 29 semantic errors
[23:33:07] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
[23:33:07] Finished 'typescript' after 10 s
amaurymartiny$
```

Now the problem comes when I save some .ts file while developing. The typescript task starts, compiles in 10s, but the typescript task doesn't finish, and it keeps slowly changing all the .js for about 30s. And BrowserSync detects these changes, so reloads constantly the pages during these 30s.

I made here a screenshot video so that you can see the phenomena: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r63zuDtQEeg. As you can see, BrowserSync detects file changes for a way too long time, sometimes it detects the same .js file changing twice.

Can someone help me solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: **beware:** The play button from the link opens a new ad window along with the intended video. @amaurymartiny, please pick a different video hosting service.

Comment: './**/* can be very slow, limit to more specific